# Odoo container stopped and removed, but odoo is still being executed

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-12

I'm learning how to deploy odoo with docker-compose, and how to configure it. I'm being teached how to create modules, and what appeared in my teacher's screen didn't correspond to what appeared in mine. So I decide to run a `docker-compose down` to try and see if restarting the whole process helps. Just to make sure, I erased my browser's cache data and reloeaded the odoo tab, and to my surprise it was still running. I check with `docker ps -a` and there are no odoo containers created in my system. Is there any way to check where this odoo instance is coming from, or has anyone had a similar experience?

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:12.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

My odoo.conf file, which is inside the ./config folder.

```
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo
admin_passwd = 12345678
```

I'm using Windows 10 Education and Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Change version to '3' and apply some changes

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'        # <-- Change to version '3'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:12.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    networks:       # <-- Add this
      - random_name # <-- Add this
    environment:                # <-- Add this
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres    # <-- Add this
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo  # <-- Add this
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo      # <-- Add this
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons

  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    expose:         # <-- Add this
      - 5432        # <-- Add this
    networks:       # <-- Add this
      - random_name # <-- Add this
    volumes:
      - "odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata:rw" # <-- add ':rw' at this end read_write

volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
networks:       # <-- Add this
  random_name:  # <-- Add this
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer, but it keeps happening. I added a colon after the "random_name" of the last line, it failed otherwise. Did the `docker-compose up`, checked it was working, all fine, then `docker-compose down`, containers stopped and removed nicely, then checked localhost:8069 once again and it was still working.